# sql statements to json

Tags: sql, json

I am looking to implement a program that converts SQL statement strings to JSON format. Any tips or methods for how to do this would be great. 
Specifically I am looking to do something similar to the DB2 and MongoDB JSON formats.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE age < 25
```

Would be translated to:

```
db.people.find(
   { age: { $lt: 25 } }
)
```

in both MongoDB and DB2 JSON.

Another generic JSON query expression could also be:

```
{ people : { age: { $lt: 25 } } }
```

I am targeting both `select` and `insert` functionality.

Any pointers to how could I could implement this, preferably in Java but I am open, would be much appreciated. I am NOT interested in merely returning results from existing SQL databases in JSON formats.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for tools are off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Well, I have to implement this myself, there are no tools for this. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Got it. Edit makes it clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2016 supports FOR JSON Clause, which supports this kind of conversion out of the box.

First you have to split your SQL Statement into Table Storage based on WHERE, SELECT etc and then use FOR JSON clause.

Read more about [JSON return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server#return-data-from-a-sql-server-table-formatted-as-json)

Comment: I know how to use FOR JSON clause to return results as JSON arrays. How can I use it to return the statement string as JSON?